# Component time to load

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using 'Navigator' and rendering multiple component by route. I want to show loader (like any image or text 'Loading...') before render to component because those are taking time to load. Please review my code and suggest me where should I use loader.
    Route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity, InteractionManager
} from 'react-native';

import Home from './Home';
import Tomo from './App';
import Profile from './Profile';

var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, {
  snapVelocity: 10,
  edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,
});
var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
  springTension: 300,
  springFriction: 10,
  gestures: {
  pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
}
});

export default class Route extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {renderPlaceholderOnly: true};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({renderPlaceholderOnly: false});
    });
  }

  _configureScene(route) {
    return CustomSceneConfig;
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.renderPlaceholderOnly) {
      return this._renderPlaceholderView();
    }
    return (
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'Home'}}
          configureScene={this._configureScene}
          renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}

        />
    );
  }

  _renderPlaceholderView() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  header() {
    return (
       <View>
         <Text>Loading...</Text>
       </View>
    );
  }

  navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
    _navigator = navigator;
    switch (route.id) {
    case 'Home':
      return (<Home navigator={navigator} title="Home"/>);
    case 'Tomo':
      return (<Tomo navigator={navigator} title="Tomo"/>);
    case 'Profile':
      return (<Profile navigator={navigator} title="Profile" />);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you doing any network operation before loading the component?

Comment: No, just rendering the component.One of component including more files so that taking time to load.

Comment: ok. There is no problem in the code you have posted. Can you post the code of components which is causing the delay while navigating from source to destination component.

Comment: This code is in 'Tomo' component: render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={this.onSend}
        setModalVisible={this.setModalVisible}       
        renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
        renderCustomView={this.renderCustomView}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
      />
    );
  }

Comment: and other two component is working fine.

Comment: Either the issue is in GiftedChat component or renderCustomView or renderBubble. Not possible to find the cause without seeing those code. Please update the question with the code instead of posting in comments.

Comment: there are using many component in 'Tomo' component so that taking time to load how is it possible to code fo 10 component in my post?

Comment: Hi Jickson, I can send you code on your email id(jicksonste****@****.com) if  you able to see that. I really need help

Comment: Sure. Send me, I will check

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you post your code in github and post the link here. So that even others will be able to help you

Comment: sent you plz check

Answer (score 1):

Create a base component as the container for other components(`Home`, `Tomo`, `Profile`). This container also contains a `Loading` component. So every component in this container would have a loading effect. The key codes like this:

```
class BaseContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLoading: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    ......

    return (
      {this.props.children}
      {
        this.state.showLoading ? <Loading /> : ''
      }
    );
  }

  ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I am new in react native and want to know that where should I use Route.js file having navigator code: render(){ 
 
navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
    _navigator = navigator;  
    switch (route.id) {  
       case 'Home':
        return (<Home navigator={navigator} title="Home"/>);
       case 'Tomo':
        return (<Tomo navigator={navigator} title="Tomo"/>);
      case 'Profile':
        return (<Profile navigator={navigator} title="Profile" />);
    }
  }

Comment: and when should I keep false  showLoading state( this.state.showLoading) ?

Comment: Do you use some component for routing? It is better to choose one for your app's routes, such as `react-native-router`( https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router ) . When you have done your time-consuming thing, just change the showLoading state to `false`, the component would be rendered   again without a `Loading` component.

Comment: I updated the post with Route.js file. Please review.